# Why did my login failed? Error: Invalid credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have my Userschema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
username: {...},
   },
    name: {
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Please add an email'],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    profile: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['user', 'admin'],
      default: 'user',
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please add a password'],
      minlength: 8,
      select: false,
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date,
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  },
);
```

Signup and hash methods

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) {
    next();
  }
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(13);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});

userSchema.methods.getSignedJwtToken = function () {
  return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE,
  });
};

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};
```

I can signup without any problems,using POSTMAN
Image from MongoDb Cloud
[image]

Now I want to login(Added console.log)

```
boki@gmail.com boki32300
POST /api/v1/auth/login 401 1146.328 ms - 232
Error: Invalid credentials
    at /home/milenko/blog_mongo/backend/controllers/auth.js:46:17
```

Auth.js

```
exports.login = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse('Please provide an email and password', 400));
  }
  console.log(email, password);
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

  if (!user) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid credentials', 401));
  }

  const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password);

  if (!isMatch) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid credentials', 401));
  }

  sendTokenResponse(user, 200, res);
});
```

isMatch is false.
Why?

Comment: Do you need to return from `userSchema.methods.matchPassword`? At the moment it is returning `undefined`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks,works fine now.you can add answer,.

Comment: It’s ok. I consider this sort of thing a typo